# Trim @required variables using get set in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pass a few basic strings to a User Model and then on set the strings are trimmed, but my issue is if I make the passed variables to User `@required` and using the usual way of using `set` and `get` give me the error `" Named optional parameters can't start with an underscore"`

```
class User {
  String id;
  String lastName;
  String email;


  String _firstName;
  String get firstName => _firstName;
  set firstName(String name) => _firstName = name.trim();


  User({@required this.id, 
        @required this._firstName, // Error thrown here
        @required this.lastName, 
        @required this.email});
}
```

If I do the following I get static analysis errors on the `set` and `get` variables saying `The declaration '_firstName' isn't referenced. Try removing the declaration of '_firstName'`

```
class User {
  String id;
  String lastName;
  String email;


  String firstName;
  String get _firstName => firstName; // Static analysis error here
  set _firstName(String name) => _firstName = name.trim(); // Static analysis error here


  User({@required this.id, 
        @required this.firstName, 
        @required this.lastName, 
        @required this.email});
}
```

Am I using get and set wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : In my opinion, in your case, there is no need to use getters and setters (see [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#getters-and-setters) :

```dart
class User {
  String id;
  String lastName;
  String email;
  String firstName;

  User({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.firstName,
    @required this.lastName,
    @required this.email,
  }) {
    firstName = firstName.trim();
  }
}
```

Usage :

```dart
final user = User(
    id: '1',
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    email: 'john@doe.com',
);
// set firstName :
user.firstName = 'Jane';
// get firstName :
print(user.firstName);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution i was looking for, not having to use a get set at all is great.

Comment: You should read the [dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

Answer (score 0):

With getters and setters you expose a way to either get/set a value to local/private object.

Something like,

```
String get firstname => _firstName;

set firstName => _firstName = name.trim();
```

From the code you've shown, if all you're trying to do, is return a trimmed value, you can do that with only getter. Your code in that case might look as follows.

```
class User {
  String id;
  String email;
  final String name;


  String get firstName => name.trim();
  String get lastName => name.trimLeft(); //some other calculation


  User({@required this.id, 
        @required this.name, 
        @required this.email});
}
```